# Is it possible to perform bottom up xpath query that only returns connected parent nodes

Tags: xml, xpath

This relates to another recently posted question.  Given the sample XML below which has an 'items' node at the top with multiple nested 'item' nodes, all of which have a child 'name' node. Items have other nested 'items' that are from 2 to 7 levels deep.  The bottom 'item' node is one that does not have a child 'item' itself but can have other children.

Based on text contained at the lowest level I want to return all the parent nodes leading to that bottom element (the end game is a treeview with only relevant branches visible).

I had thought this was the solution:

```
//item[not (item) and contains(name, 'egg')]//ancestor::item
```

This does return all the nodes that I want but they all at the same level without the parent / child relationship.

Something like this comes closer but only works for the top level 'item' node and excludes the bottom element containing the search string:

```
//chapters/item[.//item [not (item) and contains(name, 'egg')]]
```

Based on the sample below I want to get:

```
item 1
    item 1.1
        item 1.1.1
            item 1.1.1.1 ham and eggs
item 2
    item 2.3
        item 2.3.1 egg salad
```

Here is the sample:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<items>
    <item>
        <name>item 1</name>
        <other>additional text</other>
        <other1>more additional text</other1>
        <item>
            <name>item 1.1</name>
            <other>additional text</other>
            <other1>more additional text</other1>
            <item>
                <name>item 1.1.1</name>
                <other1>more additional text</other1>
                <item>
                    <name>item 1.1.1.1 ham and eggs</name>
                    <other1>more additional text</other1>
                </item>
            </item>
        </item>
        <item>
            <name>item 1.2</name>
            <other>additional text</other>
            <other1>more additional text</other1>
            <item>
                <name>item 1.2.1</name>
                <other1>more additional text</other1>
            </item>
        </item>
    </item>
    <item>
        <name>item 2</name>
        <other>additional text</other>
        <other1>more additional text</other1>
        <item>
            <name>item 2.1</name>
            <other>additional text</other>
            <other1>more additional text</other1>
            <item>
                <name>item 2.1.1</name>
                <other1>more additional text</other1>
                <item>
                    <name>item 2.1.1.1 ham and sausage</name>
                    <other1>more additional text</other1>
                </item>
            </item>
        </item>
        <item>
            <name>item 2.2</name>
            <other>additional text</other>
            <other1>more additional text</other1>
            <item>
                <name>item 2.2.1</name>
                <other>more random text</other>
                <item>
                    <name>item 2.2.1.1 sausage</name>
                    <other1>more additional text</other1>
                </item>
            </item>
        </item>
        <item>
            <name>item 2.3</name>
            <other>additional text</other>
            <other1>more additional text</other1>
            <item>
                <name>item 2.3.1 egg salad</name>
                <other>more random text</other>
            </item>
        </item>
    </item>
</items>
```

Comment: Would you mind posting sample input and output data?

Comment: Thanks for response - I've created some sample xml with what I would like to get out.

Comment: What is the desired output? And do you just need the xpath, thats it?

Comment: Can you just not use `//name[. = 'item 1.1.1.1 ham and eggs']` and `//name[. = 'item 2.3.1 egg salad']` respectively. Also see if [this](https://recalll.co/app/?q=xml%20-%20Is%20there%20a%20way%20to%20get%20a%20%22reverse%22%20XPath%20in%20Scala?) is relevant.

Comment: I want to use the output to build a treeview (there's an example in my post of the items and relationship).  This is a learning exercise so the xpath would be a good start if it's even feasible.

Answer (score 1):

The essential problem with this:

```
//item[not (item) and contains(name, 'egg')]//ancestor::item
```

is that, while everything I need is returned, the ancestor nodes contain child 'item' elements I don't want and lower level elements returned separately by the xpath already exist within one or more ancestor.  However, it does have enough information to determine what I don't need and the obvious solution is run the xpath and have some additional logic to remove unwanted nodes from the node list.